# I am trying to plot a piecewise function in r

Tags: r, math

c and p are dependents. c and p are constants for some interval then linear functions after K or before respectively. I don't know what is wrong. An example would be plotting a function Y, Y = 3 for  0 < x < 2, Y = x + 3 for x >= 3. Then I plot Y and my domain is (0,10).

```
plot_options1 <- function(K, f_c, f_p, a, b){
  x = a:b
  if (x <= K){
    c = -(K + f_c)
   } else {
      c = x - (K + f_c)
    }
  if (x >= K){
    p = -f_p
   } else {
      p = (K - f_p) - x
    }
  call_leg = paste("Call", K + f_c, sep = " ")
  put_leg = paste("Put", K - f_p, sep = " ")
  plot(x, c, type = "l", col ="green", lwd = 1, xlab = "Stock Price", ylab = "Profit", xlim = c(-1,b), ylim = c(-1.5 * (f_p+K), 1.5 * (f_p + K)))
  par(new = TRUE)
  plot(x, p, ylim=range(c(c,p)), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", col = "red", type = "l")
```

Comment: can you give us a [mcve]?  (What's the [matlab] tag for?)

Comment: Should be [math] tag, miss clicked. c = -2 for x < 3, c = x - 2 for x>=3   p = 3 for x < 3, p = -x + 4 for x >= 3. Then plot c and p over a shared plot

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to correct that ... and please do give us a reproducible example.

Comment: You define function `plot_options1()`, but you don't ever use it.